# Table formula for org spreadsheet

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-table

I have a table as follow:

```
| Xn | S | Pn |
| 0  | 0 | 0  |
| 1  | 0 | 1  |
| 0  | 1 | 0  |
| 1  | 1 | 0  |
```

I would like to search through columns `Xn` and `S` and return the value of `Pn` for which `Xn=1 and S=0`.

Can anyone advise on how I could go about doing this?

Answer (score 5):

```
#+tblname: example-table
| Xn | S | Pn |
|  0 | 0 |  0 |
|  1 | 0 |  1 |
|  0 | 1 |  0 |
|  1 | 1 |  0 |

#+source: compute-table
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var table=example-table
(require 'cl)
(loop for (xn s pn) in (rest table)
      when (and (= xn 1) (= s 0)) collect pn)
#+end_src

#+results: compute-table
| 1 |
```

Answer (score 2):

Use org-babel: Name the table and use it as input for a function that does the search in a language of your choice (out of the many languages supported by org).

In pseudo code:

```
#+tblname: my_table
|Xn|S|Pn|
| 0|0|9 |
[...]

#+name filter_table
#+begin_src lang :var tbl=my_table :results output
  filter tbl # tbl (my_table by default) is passed in as array of arrays (or list of lists)
  print matching Pn
#+end_src
```